# Is it correct to say "Getting out of schedule" or "Going out of schedule"

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

Let me put some context: We have a day of tech sessions, so what I'm trying to say to a partner is that he better prepare well his time (about 60 minutes per session) so he won't run out of time because we don't want the sessions to overlap.

So, instead of saying

> We don't want the sessions to overlap

is it correct to say

> We don't want to get/go out of the schedule

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither "get out of the schedule" nor "go out of the schedule" is correct. Though somewhat informal, the idiom you are looking for is "get off-schedule," as in:

> We don't want to get off-schedule.

Answer (score 4):

> *You'd best be prepared, as we don't want to get/fall/run [behind](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/schedule) schedule (with the timing of the sessions)*.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it would be best to be clear and precise about what you're wanting communicate.

I would use:

> We had best be prepared, as we *don't want to go over the scheduled time*, as to *avoid having the the sessions to overlap*.

More generally you might use *depart from the schedule*. This could include meaning starting early etc.

eg.

> We'd been planning on visiting the winery in the afternoon, and then catching up with friends for dinner. But we decided to *depart from schedule* and we visited it in the morning, we couldn't wait!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it gave me better writing ideas. I voted for the other answer because I was looking for that idiom.

Answer (score 0):

*Get out of sync(h)* seems to fit the situation better, where 'sync' is an abbreviation of 'synchronicity'

> "We don't want to get out of sync".